# Convert image bank using parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, gnu-parallel

I've a bank of images and I used to use ImageMagick Convert to resize them, but I would like to take advantage of the power of multi-core by using the `parallel` command.

The statement I use to perform the single core conversion is as follows:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec convert {} -quality 90 -format jpg -resize 240x160 ../small/{} \;
```

It works prefectly, but the problem is that, by default, convert only uses a **single core** to perform the process. So, how can I use `parallel` to use any number of cores I want to perform the same job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 |
    parallel -0 convert {} -quality 90 -resize 240x160 ../small/{}
```

Test it with `find ... | parallel --dry-run ...`

Note that I am using `find ... -print0` and `parallel -0` to match it so that filenames are null-terminated and spaces in filenames don't cause issues.

---

By default this will use all available cores. If you want to use just 2 cores, try:

```
parallel -j 2 ...
```

If you want to use all but one of your cores, try:

```
parallel -j -1 ...
```

If you want to use half your cores, try:

```
parallel -j 50% ...
```

Comment: I have added some extra details. There's an excellent PDF here https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1